# Infrared absorption spectrum of primary amides?

Tags: organic-chemistry, spectroscopy, amines

It's my understanding that the infrared absorption spectrum of primary amides beyond having a broad peak also has 2 sharp peaks representing the symmetric and antisymmetric stretch. My question is why isn't there a third peak representing a bending motion where the two hydrogen molecules bend towards each other?

Comment: Bending vibrations tend to have quite different frequencies, much lower compared to stretching vibrations. They tend to fall in regions of the spectrum which are more difficult to interpret. [This page](http://www.instruction.greenriver.edu/kmarr/Chem%20162/Chem162%20Labs/Interpreting%20IR%20Spectra/IR%20Absorptions%20for%20Functional%20Groups.htm) gives the primary amide N-H bend as 1570-1515 cm-1. So, the bend is indeed there, but the stretch is diagnostically much more useful.